# Is there a fdisk command in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

In Linux, there is a useful **fdisk** command.

Is there an analogue for this in Windows? Specifically, I need to use (something like) **fdisk -l**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is `diskpart`

[start] [run] `diskpart` `list disk`

[image]

Also, there is `wmic diskdrive`. You can use that from the command line, but you probably want to apply some filters to avoid ending up with way too much information.

```
Availability  BytesPerSector  Capabilities  CapabilityDescriptions                 Caption                               CompressionMethod  ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  CreationClassName  DefaultBlockSize  Description  DeviceID            ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  ErrorMethodology  FirmwareRevision  Index  InstallDate  InterfaceType  LastErrorCode  Manufacturer            MaxBlockSize  MaxMediaSize  MediaLoaded  MediaType              MinBlockSize  Model                                 Name                NeedsCleaning  NumberOfMediaSupported  Partitions  PNPDeviceID                                                           PowerManagementCapabilities  PowerManagementSupported  SCSIBus  SCSILogicalUnit  SCSIPort  SCSITargetId  SectorsPerTrack  SerialNumber          Signature   Size           Status  StatusInfo  SystemCreationClassName  SystemName  TotalCylinders  TotalHeads  TotalSectors  TotalTracks  TracksPerCylinder  
              512             {3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}  LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device                     0                       FALSE                    Win32_DiskDrive                      Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                                                    5.08              0                   SCSI                          (Standard disk drives)                              TRUE         Fixed hard disk media                LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                                         2           SCSI\DISK&VEN_LSI&PROD_9750-8I____DISK\5&15EE98A3&0&000000                                                                   0        0                10        0             19               L2080BGN154FA1000272  -576210269  79987195904    OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     CORE        36707           224         156224992     8222368      224                
              512             {3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}  LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device                     0                       FALSE                    Win32_DiskDrive                      Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1                                                    5.08              1                   SCSI                          (Standard disk drives)                              TRUE         Fixed hard disk media                LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1                                         2           SCSI\DISK&VEN_LSI&PROD_9750-8I____DISK\5&15EE98A3&0&000100                                                                   0        0                10        1             63               WQC05071864F9000A2CB              2999965248000  OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     CORE        364725          255         5859307125    93004875     255                
              512             {3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}  LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device                     0                       FALSE                    Win32_DiskDrive                      Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2                                                    5.08              2                   SCSI                          (Standard disk drives)                              TRUE         Fixed hard disk media                LSI 9750-8i    DISK SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2                                         1           SCSI\DISK&VEN_LSI&PROD_9750-8I____DISK\5&15EE98A3&0&000200                                                                   0        0                10        2             63               P6901YFP93CC9C000C66  -900772765  144987010560   OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     CORE        17627           255         283177755     4494885      255                
                                                                                   Generic Flash HS-COMBO USB Device                        0                       FALSE                    Win32_DiskDrive                      Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3                                                    4.44              3                   USB                           (Standard disk drives)                              TRUE                                              Generic Flash HS-COMBO USB Device     \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3                                         0           USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_GENERIC&PROD_FLASH_HS-COMBO&REV_4.44\070809103045&1                                                                                                                                                  0                          OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     CORE
```

Comment: Do you know if `diskpart list disk` or `wmic diskdrive` will perform consistency checks on the partition table like `sudo fdisk -l` [does in Linux](http://askubuntu.com/a/335825/567783)?

Comment: I never used them on broken partitions or tested for that.

Answer (score 4):

OK, there is no doubt that `diskpart` is a nice tool for windows partitions, but it looks like it can only read or edit the windows local disk and its patitions, it could not recognize the disk file like `MBR`, `recovery`, or `EBR1` partition file which you see in the linux filesystem;
So there is really exist a tool which match `fdisk` a lot in Windows system, it's a cmd tool, this is its name and download website:

[GPT fdisk download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/)

and this is its picture of recognize my **MBR** file:

[GPT fdisk screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XtxS.png)

It has similar syntax with `fdisk -l filename`, you can use `gdisk64.exe -l filename`.

The download page also include its offical website, you can get more usage form it!
or just use the `gdisk64.exe /?` in cmd for more *_*

Comment: Don't forget disks are addressed as \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE#

Answer (score 0):

I just used 'clear-disk' to **remove a partition table** to regain control of a USB drive.  Specific steps from [an online guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-partition-and-format-a-drive-using-powershell/):

1. Open Powershell prompt as 'Administrator'
2. **get-disk**
3. Identify the number of the disk you want to re-partition.  E.g. 3
4. **clear-disk -number 3 -removedata**
5. Use the usual disk management tool to create partition table and volumes